# how to fix the problem of google play store?

Tags: google-play-store

I have accidentally uninstalled the google play store updates. Now the play store is showing error and not working. The error message is continuously popping out which is very annoying. How to get it fixed?

Comment: Give us a screenshot of the error.

Comment: Exact wording of "The error message" might make this question answerable. Another good idea is to check with our [google-play-store tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/google-play-store/info) if your error is listed there.

Answer (score 1):

Try each of these things at a time and then open the Play Store app to see if it works again.

1. **Clear the Play Store cache**: `Settings` > `Apps` > Tap All > `Google Play Store` then tap the `Clear cache` button.
2. **Clear the Play Store data**: `Settings` > `Apps` > `Google Play Store`, tap
   `Clear data`.
3. **Try downloading one of the latest Play Store APKs** from [here](https://www.apkmirror.com/?s=play%20store&post_type=app_release) and installing it. Make sure you've enabled installation from Unknown Sources (`Settings` > `Security` > Check `Unknown sources`).